# Java Inheritance getting all methods of child class based on object type

Tags: java, inheritance

I have three classes `AbstractResumeOrchestrator`, `Pattern1orhcestrator` and `Pattern2orhcestrator`.

Latter two extends this `AbstractResumeOrchestrator`.

`AbstractResumeOrchestrator` itself extends `AbstractOrchestrator`.

A call to `execute` method in `AbstractOrchestrator` object invokes the following mentioned method:

```
public abstract class AbstractResumeOrchestrator extends AbstractOrchestrator<OnboardingSessionDTO> 
{ 
    protected OrchestratorResponse execute(final OnboardingSessionDTO onboardingSessionDTO, final KVPContext kvpContext) throws Exception {
        // based on the object's class that extends AbstractResumeOrchestrator 
        // get it's all functions - it could be pattern1 or 2 orchestator
        Method method = Pattern1Orchestrator.class.getDeclaredMethod();
    }
}
```

I want to get all the methods or the orchestrator based on whether it's Pattern1 or Pattern2. I cannot change `execute` method's parameter signature for passing child class name.

How can i do this most efficiently?

Comment: Are you interested in methods that are not present in a Parent class?

Comment: Yes, if my orchestrator is Pattern1 type then i need all methods of pattern1 and similarly for pattern2.

Comment: Why don't you make this method abstract? and implement it in the Pattern1Orchestrator and Pattern2Orchestrator and call it on instances of these objects.

Comment: Are you saying that you want your abstract class to become aware of its own concrete sub-classes?  It kinda defies the whole polymorphic behavior.

Comment: Thing is both patterns call multiple downstream services and i wrote AbstractResumeOrchestrator  to save the status of service calls for a request. This resume logic should be reusable for all different patterns. I don't think taking logic inside the child classes will be optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want child class specific behavior in `execute()` you should really consider overriding that method in particular subclass with that functionality.

If you still want to do it in parent class(not recommended), you can use `instanceof` as below:

```
if(this instanceof Pattern1orhcestrator){ 
    Method method = Pattern1Orchestrator.class.getDeclaredMethod();
    //your logic
}
else if(this instanceof Pattern2orhcestrator){ 
    Method method = Pattern2Orchestrator.class.getDeclaredMethod();
    //your logic
}
```

The reason it is bad idea to have this in parent class is that parent class have to know about all sub classes and sub class specific behaviors thereby making it difficult to add new classes that extend parent.

Comment: the catch here is that `//your logic` is same for both scenarios. what i actually need is just fetching right method functions corresponding to orchestrator. Something like `this.class.getDeclaredMethods()`?

Comment: May be I'm not getting your problem completely, but you can easily move `//your logic` to end of `if-else` if its common or add any other shared code. What `If-else` does is equivalent of `this.class.getDeclaredMethods()` . Hope this helps.